# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. session does not exist

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, specflow

I have the following specflow test that passed if i run it independently however when i run it in a suite i get the following error when i reaches the table:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. session
>   82486589-6a16-4b60-9503-c25a886698e7 does not exist

Here is example of the Specflow Scenario:

```
Scenario: New Register user

Given I Navigate to 'https://somewebsite.com/'
And Click element with link text 'Register'
And I wait for '5' seconds
When Enter the following new user details:

| Username | Password   | Email            | Firstname | Lastname | Time Zone       |
| Bobby    | password99 | some@email.com   | Bob       | smith    | GMT ------ U.K. |
And I take a screenshot and save it as 'SmartBear new user information' in 'C:\AutomationScreenShots'
And I click 'Register' button*
```

Any help will be gratefully appreciated

Comment: There is probably some issues in your steps. Could you post the code for them. Especially for the access of the web driver instance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your test itself, this is something related your selenium server. Could you tell me more about your setup? Are you using selenium grid or a local selenium server instance?